# JSTL: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Tags: java, spring-boot, jstl

I'm using JSTL in SpringBoot to loop and get all item in Beans. But when I get the result I received an error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
```

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String content;
// Get and Set
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface ManufacturerRepository extends CrudRepository<Manufacturer, Integer> { 
}
```

Service class:

```
public interface ManufacturerService {
  Iterable<Manufacturer> listAllManufacturers();
}
```

Service Impl class:

```
@Service
public class ManufacturerServiceImpl implements ManufacturerService {

 private ManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository;

 @Autowired
 public void setManufacturerRepository(ManufacturerRepository manufacturerRepository) {
       this.manufacturerRepository = manufacturerRepository;
 }

 @Override
 public Iterable<Manufacturer> listAllManufacturers() {
      return manufacturerRepository.findAll();
 }
 }
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ManagementManufacturerController {
 private ManufacturerService manufacturerService;

@Autowired
public void setManufacturerService(ManufacturerService manufacturerService) {
    this.manufacturerService = manufacturerService;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/manufacturer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    model.addAttribute("manufacturers", manufacturerService.listAllManufacturers());

    return "manageManufacturer";
}
}
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="renter" items="${manufacturers}" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${renter.id}" />
    <c:out value="${renter.name}" />
    <c:out value="${renter.content}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Log message:

```
  Stacktrace:] with root cause

  javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageManufacturer_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(manageManufacturer_jsp.java:107)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageManufacturer_jsp._jspService(manageManufacturer_jsp.java:74)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
```

I have tried change attribute name: *items="${manufacturers}"* but it's same error, How to fix the problem ? thank you

Comment: Have you tried changing your Service to return a List instead of an Iterable? According to this old thread Iterable is not supported in forEach: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44284

Comment: Hi @rkcpi: thanks for your answer, I have changed List by Iterable, and it same error

Comment: `Iterable` is not an `Iterator`, you need to get the `Iterator` with `Iterable#iterator()`

Comment: Hi @AxelH: Could you tell me more detail ?

Comment: Read the duplicate ... there you will found the restriction of type you can pass to `forEach`. Then you will get it.